# Store instance for usage in nested map/object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really annoying scope issue for my JQuery Widget. Essentially I need to access the widget instance (this) inside of my map/object `options`.

Is it possible to do this? Any advice how I can achieve this?

```
$.widget( "my.myWidget", {

    // Below 'this.defCallback' will be undefined
    // How can I store 'this' (the widget instance) in a variable??
    options: {
        callback: this.defCallback  // allow user to overwrite/provide custom callback
    },


    ....


    defCallback: function() {
        console.log('defCallback');
    }
});
```

If I had a nested function I know I can easily solve this but I have a nested object/map which makes things difficult.

```
function foo {
    var _this = this;

    ...

    var bar = function() {
        // easily access this
        _this.defCallback();

        ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$('<div></div>')
    .myWidget();  // use defCallback

$('<div></div>')
    .myWidget({
        callback: function() {
            ...
        }
    });  // use custom callback
```

**Edit:** How the callback function is 'bound' and called:

```
    _create: function() {
        this.element.click( this.options.callback );
    }
```

.click(value.callback(_this)

Comment: Can you also show the code that invokes the `callback` function?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you could dynamically change the context of a function with the *apply()* and with *call()* methods.

On es5 you could use *bind()*.

So your code:

> _create: function() {
>          this.element.click( this.options.callback );
>       }

Became with *apply()*:

```
_create: function() {
    var el = this.element;
    var callback = this.options.callback;
    el.click(function() {
         callback.apply(el);
         // If you have parameters:
         // callback.apply(el, arguments || array);
    });
}
```

With *call()*:

```
_create: function() {
    var el = this.element;
    var callback = this.options.callback;
    el.click(function() {
         callback.call(el);
         // If you have parameters:
         // callback.call(el, arg0, arg1, ...);
    });
}
```

With *bind()*:

```
_create: function() {
    this.element.click(this.options.callback.bind(this));
}
```

**UPDATE**

As your issue is to have the *this* reference binded inside the object definition you need to change your code.

The quick way is is to emend it like this (from your fiddle):

```
var mw = {
    defCallback: function () {
        alert("abc");
    },
    _create: function () {
        //this.populateOptions();
        alert("Is undefined: " + this.options.isUndefined);  // outputs 'true'
        this.element.click(this.options.callback.bind(this));
    },
    populateOptions: function() {
        if (this.options.callback === undefined)
            this.options.callback = this.defCallback;
    }   
};
```

So you first define your object with the parent attributes and functions.

```
mw.options = {
    //accessObjectParent: this.instantiator,
    isUndefined: (mw.defCallback === undefined), // this refers to the map/object 
    // Can I access the maps 'parent'/instantiator?
    // this.instantiator.defCallback ???
    callback: mw.defCallback
};
```

Than you attach the *options* object and you could refer on the parent object instead of using *this*.

$.widget( "my.myWidget", mw );

And now you pass the object on your widget declaration.

Comment: that doesn't work, the problem is in storing the function reference inside `this.options`. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/va4ge5as/4/